# how to remove multiple duplicates from a list?

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to write a program that plays a game of go fish between two players
and i currently stuck trying to remove the duplicates in the first hand dealt.

This is the code i have so far, and it only removes one dupe. I was wondering if anyone can help me enhance it by allowing to remove all dupes

```
#sorts player1 cards and removes the pairs
player1.sort()
print "hand for player 1:"
print cards.hand_string(player1)
newplayer1 = []
player1points = 0

newplayer1, player1points = cards.drop_pair(player1)
print cards.hand_string(newplayer1)
```

s=spades
d=diamonds
h=hearts
c=clubs

for this game a player will get 8 cards each for ex
`TS TD JH QS QC AC AD AH`

my code results in this
`JH QS QC AC AD AH`
i want it to result in this
JH AH

thank you in advance

Comment: Why do you want the AH? how are you selecting which of the aces aren't paired? or do you really just want the JH?

Answer (score 2):

If the ordering does not matter: use a set() or dict() instead. Otherwise you have to iterate over the whole list and remove items from the list. Or you maintain the ordered list and keep track of the unique items in the list through a second dict. Before inserting a new item to the list you check first if the item exists already in side the dict - this is adviceable for large list - perhapse overkill for small lists.

Answer (score 1):

Use sets. http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set

Answer (score 0):

You could call that function that removes one dupe again and again until there are no dupes left.

Answer (score 0):

So as I see it the suit does not matter in matching.  unique_hand_values = [h[0] for h in hands] gets a list of all of the card values (no suit).

From there you can loop and compare since they are sorted in order:

```
for index, hand_value in enumerate(unique_hand_values): 
    if index + 1 < len(hand_value) and hand_value == unique_hand_values[index + 1]:
        # its a duplicate
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

player1 = ['TS', 'TD', 'JH', 'QS', 'QC', 'AC', 'AD', 'AH']
new_player1 = []

groups = groupby(player1, key=itemgetter(0))
for key, group in groups:
    group = list(group)
    if len(group)%2:
        new_player1.append(group[-1])

print new_player1
```